# Sorting object by keys after grouping by recursively using lodash

Tags: angularjs, sorting, lodash

I used a mixin that will group objects by an array of properties

```
_.groupByMulti = function(obj, values, context) {
    if (!values.length) {
        return obj;
    }
    var byFirst = _.chain(obj)
        .groupBy(values[0], context)
        .value();

    var rest = values.slice(1);

    for (var prop in byFirst) {
        if (prop) {
            byFirst[prop] = _.groupByMulti(byFirst[prop], rest, context);
        }
    }

    return byFirst;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of an example : http://jsfiddle.net/61u6jr2v

I tried sorting them by adding `.sortBy("keys")` in the process, but it replaces the index, which I do not want, because I am using the keys as labels.

Comment: Where are you using `sortBy()` (I didn't see it)?

Comment: @AdamBoduch, you might want to check the fiddle, I didn't add it there so you'll see how things are grouped.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish with `sortBy()`.